# There is no subscription information in the prompt information in the show syntax

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

There is no subscription information in the prompt information in the show syntax

```
db001 ❯ show subscriptions on db001;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected TABLES or DATABASES or SERIES or TAG or QUERIES or STREAMS or DATANODES, found: subscriptions"}
```

version:cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 842fc0e

Show subscriptions only supported on enterprise edition.
I am using the enterprise version. What I am referring to here is: there is no subscription information in the show syntax error return.
The info only contain as follow:

```
Expected TABLES or DATABASES or SERIES or TAG or QUERIES or STREAMS or DATANODES
```

Addition, It seems that there are no vnode here either. Make modifications here too.

```
public ❯ show des;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: nonsupport: des"}
```

waitting sync LTS/2.3, Enterprise Edition 2.4, Enterprise Edition LTS/2.3.